# Shapes and figures: are they synonyms?

Tags: synonyms

Is there a difference between shapes and figures, or these words are synonyms in terms of geometry?
Thank you.

Comment: Your question needs to be expanded to show your understanding of the meaning of the words, along with some examples of said shapes/figures you are wondering about. *figure* has a broad usage so additional details are needed to focus on your problem.

Comment: Shape is one of the possible meanings of figure. Have a look at this dictionary definition: if that doesn't explain everything to you, please ask a more specific question. http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/figure

Answer (score 3):

In geometry, there are certain set "shapes" (outlines) that are [defined](http://www.math-only-math.com/basic-shapes.html):

2-D: circles, squares, triangles, rectangles...
3-D: cubes, cylinders, spheres...

The instances, or when they occur, are called "figures"

> A cube is a 3-D *figure*.
>   A circle is a planar *figure*.
>
> The *figure* is in the *shape* of a square.

**Example**

The definition of a square is that it has four equals sides and the angles between the sides are 90 degrees.  This defines a square's "shape", what it will look like, but since it has not been drawn, there is no "figure of a square", only the idea of its "shape".

Draw a square:

[image]

Now, that the square is drawn: the black square is a "figure" of a square.

Comment: "Look at this picture. This is a square. It's a..." Shape or figure? Which word is preferable here?

Comment: The "figure" *(picture)* has the "shape" of a square", "It is a "figure" of a square". The "figure" is the "picture", the "shape" is what it looks like.